# trouble with displaying ships names when they are sunk

Tags: c#, winforms

the problem i'm facing right now is that i don't know how to check on the opponent's move which ships it sinks so i can display a message saying "Your ____ has sunk".

this is the code i have written

```
namespace Naval
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        const int Size_grid = 10;
        const int picturebox = 50;
        PictureBox[,] playerBoard = new PictureBox[Size_grid, Size_grid];
        PictureBox[,] opponentBoard = new PictureBox[Size_grid, Size_grid];
        int[,] playerShips = new int[Size_grid, Size_grid];
        int[,] opponentShips = new int[Size_grid, Size_grid];
        int[] Lengths = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        //string[] Names = new string[] { "Αεροπλανοφόρο", "Αντιτορπιλικό", "Πολεμικό", "Υποβρύχιο" };

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < Size_grid; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < Size_grid; col++)
                {
                    PictureBox playerPictureBox = new PictureBox();
                    playerPictureBox.Size = new Size(picturebox, picturebox);
                    playerPictureBox.Location = new Point(col * (picturebox + 10) + 185, row * (picturebox + 10) + 245);
                    playerPictureBox.Click += PictureBox_Click;
                    playerPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    playerPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(playerPictureBox);
                    playerBoard[row, col] = playerPictureBox;
                }
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < Size_grid; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < Size_grid; col++)
                {
                    PictureBox opponentPictureBox = new PictureBox();
                    opponentPictureBox.Size = new Size(picturebox, picturebox);
                    opponentPictureBox.Location = new Point(col * (picturebox + 10) + 1145, row * (picturebox + 10) + 245);
                    opponentPictureBox.Click += PictureBox_Click;
                    opponentPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    opponentPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(opponentPictureBox);
                    opponentBoard[row, col] = opponentPictureBox;
                }
            }

            PlacePlayerShips(playerShips, Lengths);
            PlaceOpponentShips(opponentShips, Lengths);

        }
        private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
            int row = (pictureBox.Location.Y - 245) / (picturebox + 10);
            int col = (pictureBox.Location.X - 1145) / (picturebox + 10);

            if (pictureBox.Location.X >= 1145 && pictureBox.ImageLocation == null) // opponent board
            {
                if (row >= 0 && row < opponentShips.GetLength(0) && col >= 0 && col < opponentShips.GetLength(1))
                {
                    if (opponentShips[row, col] > 0)
                    {
                        pictureBox.ImageLocation = "x.png";
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox.ImageLocation = "-.png";
                    }
                    ComputerMove();
                }
            }
        }





        private void ComputerMove()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int row = random.Next(Size_grid);
            int col = random.Next(Size_grid);

            while (playerBoard[row, col].ImageLocation != null)
            {
                row = random.Next(Size_grid);
                col = random.Next(Size_grid);
            }

            if (playerShips[row, col] > 0)
            {
                playerBoard[row, col].ImageLocation = "x.png";
                
            }
            else
            {
                playerBoard[row, col].ImageLocation = "-.png";
            }
        }





        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void PlacePlayerShips(int[,] playerShips, int[] shipLengths)
        {
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            foreach (int shipLength in shipLengths)
            {
                int row, col;
                int direction = random.Next(2);

                int placed = 0;
                while (placed == 0)
                {
                    if (direction == 0) // Horizontal
                    {
                        row = random.Next(Size_grid);
                        col = random.Next(Size_grid - shipLength + 1);

                        // Check if ship overlaps with other ships
                        int overlap = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                        {
                            if (playerShips[row, col + i] == 1)
                            {
                                overlap = 1;

                            }
                        }

                        // Place ship if no overlap
                        if (overlap == 0)
                        {
                            placed = 1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                            {
                                playerShips[row, col + i] = 1;
                                playerBoard[row, col + i].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else // Vertical
                    {
                        row = random.Next(Size_grid - shipLength + 1);
                        col = random.Next(Size_grid);

                        // Check if ship overlaps with other ships
                        int overlap = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                        {
                            if (playerShips[row + i, col] == 1)
                            {
                                overlap = 1;

                            }
                        }

                        // Place ship if no overlap
                        if (overlap == 0)
                        {
                            placed = 1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                            {
                                playerShips[row + i, col] = 1;
                                playerBoard[row + i, col].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Change direction if ship couldn't be placed
                    if (placed == 0)
                    {
                        direction = (direction + 1) % 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void PlaceOpponentShips(int[,] opponentShips, int[] shipLengths)
        {
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            ;

            foreach (int shipLength in shipLengths)
            {
                int row, col;
                int direction = random.Next(2);

                int placed = 0;
                while (placed == 0)
                {
                    if (direction == 0) // Horizontal
                    {
                        row = random.Next(Size_grid);
                        col = random.Next(Size_grid - shipLength + 1);

                        // Check if ship overlaps with other ships
                        int overlap = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                        {
                            if (opponentShips[row, col + i] == 1)
                            {
                                overlap = 1;
                                
                            }
                        }

                        // Place ship if no overlap
                        if (overlap == 0)
                        {
                            placed = 1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                            {
                                opponentShips[row, col + i] = 1;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else // Vertical
                    {
                        row = random.Next(Size_grid - shipLength + 1);
                        col = random.Next(Size_grid);

                        // Check if ship overlaps with other ships
                        int overlap = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                        {
                            if (opponentShips[row + i, col] == 1)
                            {
                                overlap = 1;
                                
                            }
                        }

                        // Place ship if no overlap
                        if (overlap == 0)
                        {
                            placed = 1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++)
                            {
                                opponentShips[row + i, col] = 1;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Change direction if ship couldn't be placed
                    if (placed == 0)
                    {
                        direction = (direction + 1) % 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        int time = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time++;
            label42.Text= time.ToString();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label44.Text = " ";
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried adding a `switch` with choices 1-4 but it didn't work i've also tried having a `int[] ship Hits = new int[] {0,0,0,0}` and just adding 1 every time a ship was hit but that didn't go as planned because i didn't know how to bind each item of the array to a ship . and i think that's about it

Comment: Did you consider to define a class "Ship"?

Comment: You could store the ship's ID in that array instead of just an 'occupied/empty' flag. In fact each cell could hold a bunch of information in a structure instead of a simple number.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you might find helpful would be to bundle up all the information about a `Ship` into a class. This is an [abstraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) that could make it easier for **displaying ship names when they are sunk**. At the same time, use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) so that a `Ship` is still a `PictureBox` with all the functionality that implies.

---

[image: screenshot]

**Ship minimal class example**

Member properties tell us what we need know about a ship. Use `enum` values to make the intent perfectly clear.

```
class Ship : PictureBox
{
    #region P R O P E R T I E S
    [Description("Type")]
    public τύπος τύπος
    {
        get => _τύπος;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_τύπος, value))
            {
                _τύπος = value;
                switch (_τύπος)
                {
                    case τύπος.Αεροπλανοφόρο: Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(_imageDir, "aircraft-carrier.png")); break;
                    case τύπος.Αντιτορπιλικό: Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(_imageDir, "destroyer.png")); break;
                    case τύπος.Πολεμικό: Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(_imageDir, "military.png")); break;
                    case τύπος.Υποβρύχιο: Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(_imageDir, "submarine.png")); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    τύπος _τύπος = 0;

    public bool Sunk { get; set; }

    [Description("Flag")]
    public σημαία σημαία
    {
        get => _σημαία;
        set
        {
            _σημαία = value;
            onUpdateColor();
        }
    }
    σημαία _σημαία = σημαία.Player;
    #endregion P R O P E R T I E S

    private void onUpdateColor()
    {
        var color =
            Sunk ? Color.Red :
                σημαία.Equals(σημαία.Player) ?
                    Color.Navy :
                    Color.DarkOliveGreen;
        for (int x = 0; x < Image.Width; x++) for (int y = 0; y < Image.Height; y++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image;
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).R < 0x80)
                {
                    bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
        Refresh();
    }

    public Point[] Hits { get; set; } = new Point[0];
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{σημαία} {τύπος} @ {((TableLayoutPanel)Parent)?.GetCellPosition(this)}";

    private readonly static string _imageDir =
        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
}
```

---

*Where `enum` values are:*

```
enum Direction
{
    Horizontal,
    Vertical,
}
enum τύπος
{
    [Description("Aircraft Carrier")]
    Αεροπλανοφόρο = 5,

    [Description("Destroyer")]
    Αντιτορπιλικό = 4,

    [Description("Military")]
    Πολεμικό = 3,

    [Description("Submarine")]
    Υποβρύχιο = 2,
}
/// <summary>
/// Flag
/// </summary>
enum σημαία
{
    Player,
    Opponent,
}
```

---

**Displaying ships names when they are sunk**

When the inherited `Ship` version of `PictureBox` is clicked the information is now available.

```
private void onAnyShipClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Ship ship)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ship.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

Images credit: [Robuart](https://www.istockphoto.com/portfolio/robuart)
Used under license.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/naval.git) demo code.